# Pnpm package manager downgrade

Tags: javascript, npm, pnpm

What is the proper way of downgrading pnpm to an older version?
I have currently the latest version 7+, while I need version 6.32.
npm has a nice tools for it: volta or nvm, but haven't found anything for pnpm if it's intalled globally.

Answer (score 2):

> Since v16.13, Node.js is shipping Corepack for managing package managers.

https://pnpm.io/installation#using-corepack

`corepack prepare pnpm@6.32.0 --activate`

Use this command to just change the pnpm version.

All version Tags can be found on pnpms github page:
https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/tags?after=v6.32.2

Comment: Do not just give a link, make a quote.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated on this page https://pnpm.io/fr/uninstall you must delete the directory stored in the $PNPM_HOME environment variable.
So type:

```
$PNPM_HOME
```

Then delete it with the following command on linux or macOs:

```
sudo rm -rf $PNPM_HOME
```

Or by deleting the folder directly with windows

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you just need to use another version of pnpm for a particular project, just switch to another version of node with nvm, since each version has its own global packages. That way you can have pnpm 8 for node 18 and pnpm 7 for node 16